# How to add new element with some changes on clicking a button until a specific number?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

HTML code:

```
<input type='text' id='element1' />
<button id='addNew'>Add New</button>
```

I want each time on clicking the button a new input is created but with number increasing like :

```
<input type='text' id='element2' />
<input type='text' id='element3' />
..
..
<input type='text' id='element8' />
```

Until number 8 , each time I click the button an `input` is created with increased number.

```
$('#addNew').click(function(){
    //Create new element if it's not greater than 8
});
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/append is what you need, however I'd advise against creating elements with incremental `id` attributes. It quickly becomes a pain to maintain and makes your logic a lot more complicated than it would otherwise need to be. Under what circumstances do you need to identify the elements using their `id`? It may be better to use classes and/or DOM traversal depending on the situation

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming some inputs exist in the current DOM:**

- The function `count` increments `+1` in every call.
- The function `count` starts with the existing inputs `$('[type="text"]').length`.

```js
var count = function() {
  return (count.i = (count.i || $('[type="text"]').length) + 1);
}

$('#addNew').click(function(){
    var i = count();
    if (i > 8) return;
    $('body').append($(`<input type='text' id='element${i}' value="${i}"/><p>`));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type='text' id='element1' value="1" />
<p>
<button id='addNew'>Add New</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#addNew').click((function(){
    var count = 0;
    return function() {
        if(count < 8) {
           //Create new element
        }
        count++
    }
})());
```

See JavaScript closures: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recomment creating id's like this.

```js
var count =1;
$('#addNew').click(function(){
if(count<8){
  $("<input type='text' id='element"+(count+1)+"'/>").insertAfter('#element'+(count++));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='element1' />
<button id='addNew'>Add New</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#addNew').click(function(){
  var last_element = $(document).find('.element').last();
  var new_element = last_element.clone();
  var new_element_id = 'element' +(parseInt(last_element.attr('id').replace('element', ''))+1);
  new_element.
    attr('id', new_element_id).
    insertAfter(last_element);
    
  //for display purposes
  new_element.val(new_element_id);
});
```

```css
.element{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="element1" class="element" />
<button type="button" id="addNew">Add New</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="jsEleList">
        <li><input type='text' id='element1' /></li>
    </ul>
    <button class="jsAddNewBtn">Add New</button>
```

**JS**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var index = 2;
        $(".jsAddNewBtn").on('click', function(){
            if(index <= 8) {
                var data = $(".jsEleList li").first().find('input').clone();
                data.attr('id', 'element' + index);
                var li = $('<li>').append(data);
                $(".jsEleList").append(li);
            }
            index++;
        });
    });
```

Also follow the naming conventions of class names that specifically used for only js operations

Hope this may help you.